# Is RxJava Completable's Emitter.onComplete happens-before Observer's callback?

Tags: rx-java2, java-memory-model

Given the following code, is it guaranteed that `System.out.println(v)`will print 1? What if I change the io and computation schedulers to other schedulers?

I have checked the source of computation scheduler, it seems use executor's submit method and according to the documentation, submit is happens-before the execution of the actual runnable, so I think in this case, this happens-before relationship is guaranteed, but is this apply to other schedulers?

```java
import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class Test {
    static int v = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Completable.create(e -> {v = 1; e.onComplete();})
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(() -> System.out.println(v));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

also, if I assign 1 to v before `Completable#create`, is this change visible to Completable's body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the following code, is it guaranteed that System.out.println(v) will print 1?

Yes.

If you, however, swapped the order, there is no guarantee:

```
Completable.create(e -> {e.onComplete(); v = 1;})
```

> What if I change the io and computation schedulers to other schedulers?

All standard schedulers have this guarantee.

> but is this apply to other schedulers?

Any asynchronous scheduler is expected to provide this happens-before relationship and the standard ones are guaranteed because of the underlying ExecutorService.

> if I assign 1 to v before Completable#create, is this change visible to Completable's body?

`subscribeOn` is also establishes a happens-before relationship so upon subscription, the `v` is committed and the body of the create will see the value.